# Python Sudoku Recursion with Brute Force Backtracking Error

Tags: python, recursion, sudoku, backtracking

I am doing a Sudoku puzzle solver for homework, but am encountering some difficulty. The code right now cycles past the solution, although it does reach it for easy puzzles, and for harder puzzles, it gets stuck with several 9's for no apparent reason. I would appreciate any help on this. (check_cell determines if the placement is valid or not.)

1. Is backtracking implemented correctly in this code, and if not, how would that be fixed?
2. How can I stop the solver from freezing? It solves around 3 rows and then freezes, changing most of the values to 9s.

Some code:

```
def solve_helper(self, row, col):
# Try placing a number in each column of current row
    board = self.the_board
    if board[row][col] != 0:
        ?????
    elif board[row][col] == 0:
        for i in range(1,10):
            print("Setting value at i with ") + str (i) + (" located at " ) + str(row) + str(col)
            self.set_cell(row, col, i)
            self.guesses = self.guesses + 1
            if self.check_cell(row, col):
                if self.solve_helper(row, col): return True
            else:
                self.set_cell(row, col, 0)
    else:
        return self.mover(row,col)
    return False

def mover(self, row, col):
    if col + 1 != 9:
        return self.solve_helper(row, (col+1))
    elif row + 1 != 9:
        print "Moving to row" + str(row + 1)
        return self.solve_helper((row+1),0)
    else:
        print "SOLUTION FOUND"
        return True
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trouble you're having is that some of your recursive calls are not returning the results properly, so your solution, when it is found, gets forgotten about a few levels up the recursive stack. Here's the first fix that you need, adding `return` to the recursive calls made in `mover`:

```
def mover(self, row, col):
    if col + 1 != 9:
        return self.solve_helper(row, (col+1))  # added return
    elif row + 1 != 9:
        print "Moving to row" + str(row + 1)
        return self.solve_helper((row+1),0)     # here too
    else:
        print "SOLUTION FOUND"
        return True
```

You also need something similar in the special case of your `solve_helper` function where you skip over pre-solved cells. The end of the function should be:

```
else:
    return self.mover(row, col)  # added return
return False
```

**Edit:**

Ok, I've found a few more issues in the code. Two of them are logic issues with the solver, and one is a display issue that doesn't cause any real problems other than looking strange during the solving.

The issues:

1. First, you're latest code has `solve_helper` calling itself, rather than calling `mover`. This makes it take an extra function call before moving (though I think it may not actually break the solver).
2. Second, if `solve_helper` sets a cell to 9, but then in backtracked to (after some later cells couldn't be solved), the 9 doesn't get reset to zero before backtracking further.
3. And lastly, the display issue. Setting cells to 0 doesn't stop their old value from being displayed. This looked a lot like the issue in #2, (with 9s being left behind after backtracking) but in fact it is only cosmetic.

The first issue is easy to fix. Just change the `solve_helper` call to a `mover` call instead. That's actually what you had in the original code you put in the question. Calling `solve_helper` directly doesn't actually get the wrong result (since `solve_helper` will skip the already filled out cell the second time), but it adds an unnecessary extra function call to each level of your recursion.

The second issue is a little more complicated, and this is where you are getting stuck on some boards. What you need to do is move the line that does `self.set_cell(row, col, 0)` out of the `else` block it is currently in. In fact, you can actually move it outside of the loop entirely, if you want (since it only really is necessary if you're backtracking after none of the values for the current cell worked). Here is what I think this is the best arrangement of the for loop (also moving the `return False` statement up):

```
for i in range(1,10):
    print("Setting value ") + str (i) + (" at " ) + str(row) + ", " + str(col)
    self.set_cell(row, col, i)
    self.guesses = self.guesses + 1
    if self.check_cell(row, col):
        if self.mover(row, col):
            return True
print "Backtracking"
self.set_cell(row, col, 0)
return False
```

Finally, fixing the display issue requires two changes. First, get rid of the conditional in `set_cell`. You want to update the display always. Next, in `update_textfield`, move the `delete` call outside of the `if` block so that it always happens (leave the `insert` under the `if`). This makes it so that setting a cell to zero will erase the previous value, but not make it display an actual 0 character (it will show nothing).

I think this should do it. Note that the algorithm you're using is still pretty slow. Solving [a board I found on the internet in a quick Google search](http://sudokublog.typepad.com/sudokublog/sudoku_puzzles/) took 122482 guesses and more than 5 minutes, but it did finally work. Other boards (especially those that require 8s or 9s in the first few open spaces) may take even longer.

Comment: Doesn't the function as it is already skip over nonzero values, by the else statement as part of the solve_helper?

Comment: @CluelessCoder: The issue is that after you skip a non-zero value by going to the `else` block, you are always returning False, even if the solution was found. Any time you recurse, you need to ready to return `True` if that call results in finding the solution. You only want to return False when you've given up on the current board state and need to backtrack.

Comment: I'm still not sure about how the False is being passed in, and I'm not sure how to direct the non-zeros correctly. The code seems to be backtracking, but passes by the correct value, and resulting in the empty characters in three rows all turning into 9's.

Comment: @CluelessCoder I think that your changes to the `if` statement and to the recursion in `solve_helper` are wrong. All you needed was to add `return` to the lines where you were already doing function calls, both in `mover` and in the `else` case near the end of `solve_helper`. I think that should be enough.

Comment: After placing in the changes you recommended, the program still does not work. It will hang in place at the 2nd row, towards the final col, and then backtrack to set all the non-given values to 9. I've attached the full code, to see if anything else might be a problem.
http://pastebin.com/iNccTXgN

Comment: @CluelessCoder I've updated my answer with more fixes based on the code you posted. There is one serious issue, one trivial one, plus a graphics glitch that looks just like the serious issue. With those fixes applied, the code can solve real boards that I've tested it against (albeit slowly).

Comment: Thank you for the help! The code finally works now, thanks to you! I am sincerely grateful!